# Error on Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection menu

Tags: c#, mysql, indexing, datagridview

i was searching before about this matter but some answer i get seems still cannot fix my problem here my code

```
 private void delete_record()
        {
            if (menuGrid.Rows.Count > 1 && menuGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index != menuGrid.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                query = "DELETE FROM produk WHERE sn=" + menuGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,connection);
                menuGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(menuGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                MessageBox.Show("deleted");
            }
        }
```

i tried change inside if() whith simples index and it still have same error, event this code

```
 private void delete_record()
        {
                query = "DELETE FROM produk WHERE sn=" + menuGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,connection);
                menuGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(menuGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                MessageBox.Show("deleted");
         }
```

still give me same error. hope some one can tell me where i was wrong and can fix it

Comment: Either `SelectedRows` contains no items, or `Cells` for the selected row contains no items. Note that `menuGrid.Rows.Count` isn't checking if any rows are selected, it's merely checking that rows exist (and that more than one row exists at that).

Comment: Never us `SelectedRows` without checking `SelectedRows.Any()` first!

Comment: @John so i cant merely pick row and cells direcly from database?

Comment: @TaW i have to make declaration SelectedRows.Any() first before use SelectedRows?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I sense there might be some misunderstanding here. "Selected" in this context doesn't mean "rows I've SELECTed from the database". It means "rows in the datagrid that the user has selected on the UI".

Comment: Yes, you should do this test instead of relying blindly on some row being selected.

Comment: @Kohn, yup, good catch, this may indeed be the reason for the code..

Comment: sorry late reply. thx for answering my question. for past this week i tried learn more about row and cell and your answer been helpfull for me to know more